# How to identify the autogenerated trace and event telemetry in application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I want to suppress all the auto generated event and trace telemetries from the client sdk side in my code
is there any property I can use to identify the auto generated ones? for dependency and exception the sdkversion starts with rdddsdk. is there something similar for trace and event telemetry also ?

we are using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore

Comment: what's the project? a mvc project or others? and please also provide the app insights packages you're using.

Comment: its Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore

Comment: can you please let us know what's the project? console or web?

Comment: it is a web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress the auto generated message, you can try to use the `Category` property.

Most of the auto generated messages are coming from `Microsoft` category, so in the `Program.cs`, add `ConfigureLogging` method like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {                       
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            //add the following filter
            .ConfigureLogging(logging=>
                                logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.None));
}
```